# Is a 13-hour layover in the middle of the night enough time to go see Buckingham Palace?

Tags: uk, layovers, london, sightseeing

My plane lands at Heathrow at 8:30 pm on December 10 and leaves Gatwick the next morning, December 11, at 9:15 am. Do I have the time to see Buckingham Palace?

Comment: My daughter and I did Time Square, quickly, on the subway, on a short JFK layover, loved it everything was value added. Enjoy the streets of London as they should be seen on a cold winter night.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86400/discussion-on-question-by-charmaine-is-a-13-hour-layover-in-the-middle-of-the-ni).

Answer (score 73, accepted):

As you've got to make the journey between airports anyway, I say make the most of it.  Sleep on the plane if you can and see the city at night.  I'd pack in one backpack (hand luggage strapped on top) and do it on foot, but taxi/bus/night tube (Friday and Saturday) are other options.

The [last tube train](https://tfl.gov.uk/modes/tube/first-and-last-tube) from Heathrow is at 23:35 (T4) or 23:42 (T5), a few minutes later for T123.  So you should have plenty of time to clear immigration, retrieve your luggage and get the tube.  There's also the [TFL line](https://www.londontoolkit.com/travel/heathrow_connect_train.htm) train but that goes to Paddington station which is 3 km from Buckingham Palace).  You can check for planned/emergency issues online at [Transport for London's website](https://tfl.gov.uk/tube-dlr-overground/status/).

If you get the tube, you can go to Hyde Park Corner, less than 1 km away from the Palace.

In the morning I used to quite often get an early train out of London Bridge to Gatwick.  Currently that looks to be 05:35, getting in at 06:04.  That *should* be plenty early enough for most flights but you'd need to check.

Assuming you're happy to walk through the night you can see a lot of London. [Here's](https://www.strava.com/routes/16306180) a quick 10 km route suggestion I threw together.  It takes in Buckingham Palace, Parliament Square (but not [Big Ben/Elizabeth Tower](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-44580280) which is being repaired), the Embankment, Trafalgar Square, Covent Garden, the Strand (you could night-bus this bit), St Paul's Cathedral, the Tower of London and Tower Bridge.

Here's a picture in case I carelessly delete the route
[image: Picture of route on Strava]

*Night buses* from Trafalgar square will get you to many places but they're not very frequent.  I've deliberately omitted airport buses in the interest of maximising your time in London.  The tube and regional trains aren't all that expensive, and are much quicker; they're also less much affected by traffic, though there are rare delays in the middle of the night.

An alternative is to *cycle* all or part of the route - at least if you have a fairly small backpack.  There are several bike hire schemes in London.  The official (Santander-sponsored) scheme is well regarded.  It has its own [sightseeing loop suggestions](https://londonblog.tfl.gov.uk/2019/11/05/santander-cycles-sightseeing/?intcmp=60245).  I rode a route similar to the walking route I suggest above yesterday (as part of a much longer ride). The most significant difference was probably to make good use of the Embankment cycle path.  Cycling in London, at least in my limited weekend experience, compares favourably to many UK cities.

Comment: In case you can't tell, I'm rather taken with the idea!

Comment: In fact inspired by this I'm contemplating doing something similar on a bike early next year

Comment: Also you might want to use this to check before you leave for any short-notice closures https://tfl.gov.uk/tube-dlr-overground/status/?Input=&lineIds=&dateTypeSelect=Future%20date&direction=&startDate=2018-12-10T00%3a00%3a00&endDate=2018-12-10T23%3a59%3a59

Comment: I appreciate everyone else is erring on the side of caution in their estimates for time to leave as Gatwick, but to give a data point in the other direction:  I usually arrive at Gatwick about 60mins before my flight (within EU), and that’s usually tight, but I’ve not missed one yet.

Comment: Night buses are something of an experience all of their own, particularly on weekends. Since this will be a Monday night/Tuesday morning you probably won't see so many of the 'colourful characters' you might on weekends. That said, being December, there might well be a few revellers around.

Comment: @PLL it's up to the OP to decide what to do with the plenty of slack time in my idea.  Certainly if you're going to cut it fine, first thing in the morning is the right time.  I've arrived at Heathrow when told toonly to find that none of the check-in desks had opened (not for another 30 minutes)  The OP may want to get to the airport early to avoid being anxious, or  they may want to spend all night waiting for the perfect reflection of the lights of Tower Bridge on the Thames to make a good impression on Instagram.

Comment: Minor note - if seeing Big Ben is a priority, it's currently covered in scaffolding and not exactly photogenic. The rest of the Palace of Westminster is certainly nice, but...

Answer (score 54):

Yes, it's doable. Although going through central London isn't the fastest route from Heathrow to Gatwick, you have lots of time so it's not an unreasonable route to take.

You could obviously do it all by taxi, but it's also possible (and much cheaper) on public transport. You can get the underground from Heathrow to Green Park, which will take about 50 min, and then you're only a few minutes [walk across the park](https://www.royalparks.org.uk/parks/green-park/visitor-information/opening-times-and-getting-here) to the palace. You can then walk to Victoria station, and get a train to Gatwick. The last train to Gatwick is at 00:08 (though trains from other stations and coaches run through the night, and the ones from Victoria start pretty early in the morning).

Comment: At night, I'd get the tube to Hyde Park Corner, and walk to Buckngham Palace, Parliament Square, along the Embankment, Trafalgar square, Covent Garden, (along the Strand, or tube to Tower Hill) Tower of London, Tower Bridge London Bridge station for the train to Gatwick.  All walking that's about 6 miles (10 km) so perfectly doable if you pack in a rucksack, and selected for night views

Comment: To make things easier - "start pretty early in the morning" is 04:35 (arriving at Gatwick at 05:27). So there's plenty time for OP to explore London at night if they choose.  *(Also recommend seeing the christmas lights around Carnaby street this time of year - if doing a night visit)*

Comment: You can get coaches to Gatwick from Victoria Bus Station throughout the night. Evidently some people don't consider buses a viable form of transport but maybe the OP does. http://www.nationalexpress.com/nxportal2/pdf/timetables/A3.pdf

Comment: @StuartF I can understand people not wanting to take a bus from central London during the day -- heavy traffic can cause serious delays (being stuck for an hour wouldn't be super-surprising). Bit in the middle of the night, the bus should be fine and is an excellent suggestion.

Answer (score 31):

Very easily doable. But if you're going all that way in on the tube and aren't too tired, walk around - central London is quite small and easily walkable.  You could see Tower Bridge, Tower of London, Big Ben, Trafalgar Square and Picadilly Circus - all quite photogenic and iconic, even at night!

Comment: I live in London and play Ingress in central London regularly. I walk around in the dark all the time. It's safe, and it's exciting, and once you get to the river the views are amazing. Not as stunning as flying over it on the approach to Heathrow, but still very impressive. Especially Vauxhall and towards Canary Warf. A city like London does not sleep. There are night buses. They are great at night. Sit at the top front and enjoy the show.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, with Caveats. Budget for contingency - 2 hours on landing, maybe 3 for T5.  I'm not kidding about T5 at this time of year.  A morning arrival might have been better, it will be dark.

So everything else is down to visibility, you will miss peak hours. Suggest you get a driver both ways, or tube and cab. Buses do not pass the Palace. You are taking your chances with visibility as well.  Plan to be back at the Airport at 06:00, again, for contingency.

Risks:  Snow, Tube Outage, Rain, Freezing Rain, Sleet, Traffic, Holiday events (Winter Wonderland is close by).

Comment: The Tube is very reliable. Snow, freezing rain and sleet are not significant risks in central London. Visibility will probably be fine. Any snow flurry in central London tends to make the national news -- I remember once hearing a national weather forecast that said there was "A bit of snow in London Town" and completely neglected to mention that, in northern England, tens of people had been trapped in their cars overnight on the motorway by heavy snowfall.

Comment: And [citation needed] for what seems to be a claim that planes at Heathrow are routinely 2-3 hours late.

Comment: @ChrisH Ah, you're probably right. Clarification would be good, though so would some evidence: 2-3hrs is an unusually long time for immigration.

Comment: @DavidRicherby it's a while since I came into Heathrow but the non-EU queues could get very long at peak times, like when all the overnight transatlantic flights come in (so I doubt the suggestion in this answer that a morning arrival would be better)

Comment: Snow? In *December*? In **London**? Don't make me laugh.

Comment: @RobertFurber, I have to admit it was in the first two weeks of January, but I have been snowed in, in London, for several days. That was all of London, all access roads, rail and airports. I have been unable to fly to Bristol, early December, because of snow and that problem covered most of Southern England.

Comment: @RobertFurber Not **early** December, but snow in London in December is something that happens, and when it does, it can be quite impressive (I've seen Green Park or Hyde Park covered in snow at those periods, and not just a sprinkling — Winter Wonderland takes a whole new meaning!), and it can be quite disruptive (see the issues with Eurostar during the Christmas period a few years back).

Comment: @David Richerby the planes are not late, but you then have to get through immigration, I've had a 50min flight from Amsterdam and then another 2-3 hours before leaving the airport. It's a volume and staffing issue. The tube is reliable, but the number of people near Hyde Park can be an issue, there are bottlenecks. See the WW site for what they recommend.

Comment: @Willeke Yes, it does sometimes snow in London. 2010 was particularly bad, for example. But snow in London is a rare event. You can browse maps of the number of days there was now lying on the ground in December (or any other month) for 2001-2010 at the [UK Meteorological Office website](https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/climate/uk/summaries/anomacts). The only years in that decade when a significant chunk of London had snow on the ground for even one day were 2005 (zero for much of London and in the "1-4" band for the rest), 2009 (in the "4-8" band) and 2010 (craziness).

Comment: @jcaron 10th December was in fact the _exact_ day we got noticeable snowfall in London last year :-)

Comment: apologies @David Richerby I missed your comment.  I did not mean they were late, I meant that is what you should budget for. I took a flight from Amsterdam and did not leave the terminal until 3 hours after scheduled landing time. I think there were 4, maybe 5 agents processing 1000+ arrivals. So yeah, it is likely a seasonal thing.

Answer (score 3):

Per other responses, the short answer is "yes you do" but you're only going to see the outside of it.

A brief stroll back up the mall will land you at Nelson's Column, and you're near enough some night-life such as Leicester Square, or the theatres on the embankment, as well as within wandering distance (or a short tube ride) of the illuminations in Carnaby Street (Bohemian Rhapsody this year!) and there's doubtless a few others to see too.

I don't know the opening times but over the river you've got the London Eye which could provide a decent photo op too. Just a shame Big Ben is scaffolded up for repairs for the forseeable.

Answer (score 1):

It takes 45 minutes to get out of the airport and another hour to get from Heathrow to BP. You'll arrive at BP at 10.15pm. Not much to see at there at that time, so I think you'd do better to head over to Waterloo Bridge and then wander up in to Covent Garden, Leicester Square, Picaddilly Circus, and Soho. The cheapest way to get to Gatwick is by coach from Victoria Coach Station. It's a miserable trip, early in the morning, but it sure is cheap.

Comment: Surprisingly, SoHo in the middle of the night weekdays can be pretty quiet and relatively uninteresting. Different story at the weekends and if you get there not too late.

Comment: @jcaron: SoHo is in New York.

Comment: @TonyK, sorry, Soho, not SoHo. Should know better, I lived there for years!

Comment: ...but never found the awesome 'Monday night bar' ;-)