# Multimodal routing in the UK - what sites/tools?

Tags: uk, routes

When routing for non-driving travel around the UK (though a Europe-wide answer would be very interesting), is there a tool that allows a sensible mix of public transport and walking (possibly with cycling, especially bike-share schemes, possibly with ridesharing)?

This is something I've been thinking about recently*, and we've just had a [London-specific question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/144225/18491), so here's a more general version.  Such a tool would also have been handy when planning the route in [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/126342/18491).

Even with "fewer transfers" set in Google maps, it seems to avoid even quite short walks in favour of changing buses/trains.  When the buses are infrequent this can take a lot longer than walk+bus.  To route manually requires some local knowledge/guesswork about which bus stops or stations to walk to; while possible on the desktop the mobile interface isn't much help.  Traveline is worse, finding solutions using 3 buses where Google uses 2, and not even saving any walking.

One feature that might help with routing efficiently but would certainly allow planning a more interesting route would be to allow a "via" option when using public transport, as you usually can with walking/cycling/driving directions.

---

* <sub>I'd normally cycle a lot (even sometimes between cities) and drive occasionally; an injury means neither is currently an option but I can walk quickly. Planning efficient routes is proving rather tedious even within/between cities I know.</sub>

Comment: rome2rio is the most "multimodal" routing site I know.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi putting in the route I've got to do this afternoon (between specific points in 2 UK cities) r2r comes in 35% slower than a sensible route.  It uses train-train-bus instead of train-(slightly longer) bus.  On another test route, that I did on Sunday, it comes up with something equivalent to what I did, so it's capable of being helpful

Comment: What is the route you are trying? I suspect that different apps/websites will be better in different cases. e.g. Travelline seems to have been the best for me in all cases I can remember (although the CityMapper iOS app is nicer to use)

Comment: @Mark one test is Cardiff (fairly central)->Bristol (suburbs); another, the one that got me thinking about this on Sunday, is within Bristol.  Strangely Traveline (meant to be good for local stuff) does the intercity one better, and Rome2Rio (marketed for large-scale journeys) does the Bristol one better.  But trying many websites for a single route (not apps, there's only so many you can install) is as onerous as putting the effort in to the planning myself

Comment: Sorry not detailed enough to study what is happening.

Comment: @Mark if I gave more details it would reduce the question to "how can I plan this route? " that I've already planned and done, as opposed to "what tool should I (first) go to in the next /general case?"

Comment: The issue is that for me travelling does all that you are asking. So I wish to see the bad case that you have to see why you get a fail and I never do.

Comment: @Mark. I see your point. Local example as I've spent time on it: From [sglmamj] to [LWH] (station/bus stop codes work) departing 12:00 on a Sunday Traveline's fastest is 58 minutes bus-bus-walk; it also offers 1:08 with a 27 minute walk.  Getting the bus to Royate Hill [bstmdat] then walking takes 52 minutes, of which 26 is walking (I have to use Google to get the walking time because traveline says that the bus stop isn't close to any transit stops that support walking if I tell it to only give walking directions.  That concept on a normal urban road is a bug and not unique to this stop

Comment: I see a 53 minute bus-walk. Also using http://www.travelinesoutheast.org.uk/se/XSLT_TRIP_REQUEST2 I can set to fast walking and get 44 min - Your issue could be just that one bus stop is wrong in the travelline db - it is worth aslking them what the iussue is, in my experience they do answer

Comment: @Mark fixing their problems would help with one route. I've seen similar issues that could be explained by the same bug but haven't investigated further, because it's less effort to do things myself. But I'm not looking for ways to help fix their database, I'm looking for a good place to start looking. Despite the bugs this might be the best option. Still nothing less than 57 minutes using your link and Sunday 12:00 departure from here, though you gain more start time choices using  the mobile SE version while losing the option to enter stop codes.

Comment: Last comment. Websites tend to be better than mobile and if the website looks like mobile then it will have got worse.

Comment: @Mark you're right there. Until I checked your comment from earlier today, all my tests were desktop browsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Travelline. There are versions for different areas the South East one is [here](http://www.travelinesoutheast.org.uk/se/XSLT_TRIP_REQUEST2?language=en&timeOffset=15) I find it usually outperforms any of the others

This asks for start and end locations and then finds routes via walking, bus, train etc.

Travelline does have mobile apps as well.

It does also show cycling but not through bike share etc.

[Tfl](https://tfl.gov.uk/plan-a-journey/) also has a transport planner but just for London but does include its bike share scheme.

Comment: One nice thing is that traveline lets you set your walking speed - I'm considerably quicker than Google assumes (except when I'm with my daughter)

Comment: I'm still not impressed with travelline, but it does seem to be better at this than anything else